# Skydrive for Windows 7 asks login on each startup

Tags: windows-7, onedrive

I am using Skydrive desktop client for Windows 7 x64 Ultimate.
Until recently, it used to work fine.
Now, it asks me to login again every time I restart my computer.
I tried googling a nit with no answers...
What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you changed any settings?

Comment: No..not at all..

Comment: Thanks it was driving me nuts. I thought it was by design and I was looking for a setting to make it auto sign-in. Now I know it's a bug and will reinstall OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did not Unlink SkyDrive in your SkyDrive app settings then sadlythe answer is to re-install the application (according to MS Answers).

You can re-download [SkyDrive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/skydrive/download#apps) it from here.